# Pass string as parameters to execute([$string_list]) in PHP PDO

Tags: php, function, pdo

I'm looking for the best way to do what this probably can't do until the future:

```php
// Only one of these, different each time
$arg_string = "'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'";         // Unknown number of arguments!
$arg_string = "'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4'"; // Unknown number of arguments!
$arg_string = "'arg1'";                         // Unknown number of arguments!

// Where I need help
$stmt->execute([$arg_string]); // Wish I could, maybe PHP 9 will
```

My problem is that a `$string` or `$array` can't be easily passed to a `function()` as its parameters.

This is important for my work because I am creating a method to query the database and I may have an unknown number of columns or values. This is what the code will look like just before using `exec()`.

I found this [SO article *(PHP use variable to pass multiple arguments to function)*](http://PHP%20use%20variable%20to%20pass%20multiple%20arguments%20to%20function) which discusses `call_user_func_array()`. But, I can't figure out how to use `call_user_func_array()` with `execute()`. Even if I were to guess, I still would want to know what is best.

I don't mind turning `$arg_string` into an array first, or not, whatever is best.

What is the best way to do what this can't:

```
$stmt->execute([$arg_string]);
```

Comment: Don't use a string, use an array that you fill dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar can you demonstrate what that would look like?

Comment: The manual has some pretty clear examples: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php (which is always a good place to start when in doubt)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Example 5, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a string, each arg should be a separate array element.

```
$arg_array = ['arg1']; // or
$arg_array = ['arg1', 'arg2']; // or
$arg_array = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'];

$stmt->execute($arg_array);
```

Comment: To accept this answer, I need you to demonstrate starting with `$arg_string` and how you got it into the array to use. I have already been using `explode()` and others to no avail.

Comment: I think you need to go back a step. Why do you need `$arg_string` in the first place? If you're creating everything dynamically, do it by building `$arg_array` from what you need.

Comment: Or use a parsable string like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

From [PDOStatement::execute | php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

```
// Only one of these, different each time
$arg_string = "'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'";         // Unknown number of arguments!
$arg_string = "'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4'"; // Unknown number of arguments!
$arg_string = "'arg1'";                         // Unknown number of arguments!

// Where I need help
$arg_array = explode(",", str_replace(["'", ' '], '', $arg_string)); // My solution
$stmt->execute([$arg_array]);
```

Comment: Is this an answer or an addition to your question? Are you asking how to explode the string into an array?

Comment: You don't want spaces or single quotes in your array, so use `$arg_array = explode(",", str_replace(["'", ' '], '', $arg_string));`

Comment: @brombeer it is a way to get $arg_string into the explode() method as the question seeks. I found the right answer.